# Перевод дробной части из десятичной в любую систему счисления

Tags: системы-счисления

Почему мы умножаем на основание системы счисления, чтобы перевести дробную часть?

Comment: Если по простому, то как еще сдвигать точку, отделяющую целую часть от дробной вправо, пока дробная не станет нулем?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо с примером такой вопрос задавать, иначе не понятно о чём речь.

В десятичной системе счисления так:

12.12 = 1*10 + 1 + 1*10<sup>-1</sup> + 2*10<sup>-2</sup> (строго по определению десятичных дробей)

Аналогично в двоичной:

10.01<sub>2</sub> = 1*2 + 0 + 0*2<sup>-1</sup> + 1*2<sup>-2</sup> (дробная часть вводится <em>аналогично</em>)

Comment: Ничего не помогает. Теги обозначают верхний и нижний индекс.